# Getting a row based on a certain condition in sql self-join

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

For the following table, is it possible to get the result using a self-join?

Table:

```
id pId  type
-------------
1  1000  1
2  1001  1  
3  1002  1
4  1000  3
```

Expected result:

```
id pId  type
-------------
2  1001  1
3  1002  1
```

In other words, I want all the rows which has type 1, but does not have type 3.

Thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

this is a question in the context of a performance testing.
in other words, there are many rows like 1000 and 1001, 1002.

i'm trying to improve the performance using the current table structure.
but i understand that probably the table is not well-designed as well.

Comment: Why can this not be a simple `WHERE Type=1` filter?  Also, where does a "self-join" factor in?

Comment: @WillP. because 1000 could also be type 3

Comment: If that's the data you want, why do you not include `1 1000 1` in your expected result?

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA looks like he is not structuring his table right but pId 1000 could also be type 3

Comment: @Steve you read my mind. can you please explain on "not structuring his table right" part? thanks

Comment: @user3380951 IMO the table structure should be like
table 1: id pID                   
|| 
table 2: pID type

 or just one table : pID type if pID is unique. This is under the assumption that type has nothing to do with id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a self join, you could use this query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.pId, t1.type
FROM
  tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.pid = t2.pid AND t2.type=3
WHERE
  t1.type=1 AND
  t2.type IS NULL
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72310/1).

Comment: accepted this answer since it uses a self-join, as requested in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any joins - just a subselect - something like this:

```
select * from mytable t1
where not exists (select id from mytable t2 where t1.pid=t2.pid and type=3)
```